# how to find the Apache OpenOffice installation directory DEBS folder

Tags: openoffice.org

I am trying to install the latest version of Apache Open Office 4.1.6?
Directions I was following said to navigate to the Apache OpenOffice installation directory  DEBS folder.  I can't find it.  I am using this website: [How to Install Apache OpenOffice 4.1 on Ubuntu, Debian and LinuxMint](https://tecadmin.net/install-apache-openoffice-on-ubuntu-debian/).
I am on the second part of step 3.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: In terminal cd ~/Downloads (case sensitive cap D)?

Answer (score 0):

You probably missed an instruction in step 2: "after extracting..."

You will find the downloaded file `Apache_OpenOffice_4.1.6_Linux_x86_install-deb_en-US.tar.gz` in the directory where you issued the `wget` command.